# Question on role duties

Tags: discussion, questions, on-topic-definition, site-rec

I want to understand:

> What is the difference between "Technical Program Manager" and
>   "Software Development Manager" in terms of roles, responsibilities and
>   people management requirements.

Will programmers.stackexchange website will be good site for this question?

Comment: career advice is explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic]. See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6488/40980

Comment: ...TWP has a custom close reason that looks like a best fit: "Questions seeking advice on **company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies** should be directed to your manager or HR department. Questions that address only a specific company or position are of limited use to future visitors. Questions seeking **legal advice** should be directed to legal professionals. For more information, click [here](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2695)."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question would not be a good fit for the site.

The answers are highly dependent on company and opinion.  There is no general rulebook on titles in the IT field.  Apart from that we generally view career advice and questions as off topic.

This question likely is also not a good fit for the Workplace for the same reason as it being highly opinionated and company specific.

Comment: Thanks. Will try to find the answer somewhere else.